# I cannot install any packages from terminal or software centre. Please help!

Tags: software-center, package-management, java, dependencies

Whenever i try to install software from software centre, it says package dependencies cannot be resolved. I have tried restarting, sudo apt-get update/upgrade/clean. I am very new to ubuntu, and I need to install java. I also tried restarting my computer. Should i just reinstall ubuntu?

Comment: How did you get into this state?

Comment: It sounds to me that you have broken your links to the repositories. Have you checked "Software Sources"? You can use that tool to find servers for Ubuntu repositories (packages).

Answer (score 2):

Try to execute `sudo apt-get -f upgrade`. With the 'f' option it will try to fix broken dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've made lots of experimental changes and you don't especially care about keeping the configuration of the machine, it may be easiest to reinstall.  You should be able to reinstall keeping your `/home` directory - but make a backup anyhow.